# For TurboTax online's "Enter Dividend Income", what goes in the "Broker or Payer" field?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, dividends, turbotax

I am confused by this field. Should I enter the company that actually issued the dividend or my broker's name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should enter the name of the company that issued you the 1099-DIV, so the broker.  If you look at 1040 Schedule B, which is why TurboTax is asking, you'll see the instructions along the left say: "If you received a Form 1099-DIV or substitute statement from a brokerage firm, list the firm’s name as the payer and enter the ordinary dividends shown on that form."
http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sb.pdf

Note that the payer name should not affect your taxable income or tax due.  The IRS primarily cares about the total dollars, which should be reflected on page 1 of Form 1040.